Hide an injected button in iframe popups/drawers
I have a button that is injected inside an application that uses a bunch of iframes. I want to hide this button when a drawer opens or disable when a popup appears inside the application. I was able to achieve that by removing z-index of the button however the button still appears when a drawer/popup opens in an iframe. Is there a way to hide the button for drawer/popups in iframes?
This is the button:
<div class="hideMeBtn" [hidden]="hideMe">
 <button>
  class = "triggerMe"
  (click) = "doSomething()"
 <button>
</div>

Example of an iframe inside the application where the button is injected:
<div class = "iframeDiv">
 <iframe [src] ="sampleIframeURL"></iframe>
</div>

Example of a drawer inside an iframe:
<mt-drawer>
 <div class="drawer-wrapper">
  <h1> Sample drawer </h1>
 </div>
<mt-drawer>

Any kind of direction will be helpful!
